# Child class without implementation

Tags: java, oop

I have a dilemma.

```
class A {
   protected int x;
}

class B extends A {
   private int y;
}
```

And I could use this hierarchy in my code, but I wonder if it is ok to just add new class to this hierarchy:

```
class C extends A {}
```

Class C is just there for type, so I could rename A to Base and have two classes inheriting from Base, but one is exactly the same as Base class.

What is better solution?

Comment: What are you actually trying to accomplish?

Comment: Why not just use `A` in the first place instead of inheriting from it?

Comment: Sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What problem are you trying to solve?

Answer (score 1):

Class without implementation is sign of bad design, you need to create new class only when you have certain behavior that vary from parent to place to it. So in your case you don't need to create C, just rename A to Abstract, Base and make it abstract. In this way you have abstract class and implementation (A and B), in further development you may need to another implementation of type A and extends from it, only in this way you need to create class C.

Answer (score 0):

The code is an abstraction describing the business problem you are solving. There is nothing stopping you from introducing an empty class if it makes sense in your business domain. The main goal is to make the code readable, to quote Steve McConnell:

> Good code is its own best documentation. As you’re about to add a comment, ask yourself, ‘How can I improve the code so that this comment isn’t needed?’ Improve the code and then document it to make it even clearer.

However it would be discouraged if you would have to implement the same method twice in `B` and `C`. This would lead to code duplication.

This approach is usually used with interfaces in [Marker Interface Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marker_interface_pattern).